# Joining two mysql_fetch_arrays

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to piece two queries together. Below is the code I'm using.  However the table is splitting up the data.  How can I remedy this? Or what better solutions are there?

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr id='centered' >";  
    echo "<td class='leftalign'>" . $row['Quarter_Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Quarterly_yield'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Quarterly_yield'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Quarterly_yield'] . "</td>";
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result8))
{
    echo "<td>" . $row['Quarterly_yield'] . "</td>";
}
```

The 2 Queries are as follows: They are nearly identical

```
SELECT  LEFT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 4) Year,
        RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2) Quarter,
        IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2)=03,'Enero a Marzo',
            IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2)=06,'Abril a Junio',
                IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2)=09,'Julio a Septiembre',
                    IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2)=12,'Octubre a Diciembre', '')
                )
            )
        ) Quarter_Name,
        ROUND(A.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Quarterly_yield
FROM    dr_rent_carteras_trimestres A
WHERE   A.ID_CARTERA = $ID_CARTERA
AND     A.IND_RENTABILIDAD = 1
AND     LEFT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 4) = (
            SELECT MAX(left(F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 4)) - 0
            FROM   dr_rent_carteras_trimestres
            WHERE  ID_CARTERA = $ID_CARTERA 
        )
```

Here is the 2nd one:

```
SELECT  LEFT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 4) Year,
        RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2) Quarter,
        IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2)=03,'Enero a Marzo',
            IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2)=06,'Abril a Junio',
                IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2)=09,'Julio a Septiembre',
                    IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2)=12,'Octubre a Diciembre', '')
                )
            )
        ) Quarter_Name,
        ROUND(A.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Quarterly_yield
FROM    dr_rent_carteras_trimestres A
WHERE   A.ID_CARTERA = $ID_CARTERA
AND     A.IND_RENTABILIDAD = 1
AND     LEFT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 4) = ( 
            SELECT MAX(left(F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 4)) - 1
            FROM   dr_rent_carteras_trimestres
            WHERE  ID_CARTERA = $ID_CARTERA 
        )
```

Comment: Look inside manual for `array_merge()`.

Comment: what are the 2 queries? they could perhaps be combined

Comment: I added the queries to my post

Comment: how about using UNION between them? However if you wrote that you know a lot more SQL than me :-)

Comment: Fetch the full arrays, then merge them.  or loop and check the row is right and insert from the second array.  then loop the full merged array to display.

Comment: Is there any reason why you have a field called `ANOTRIMESTRE` instead of two fields, `ANO` and `TRIMESTRE`? Not only does it make your queries unnecessarily complicated (see above), but it also hinders your ability to use indexes. Another thing I'd suggest is to leave the quarter's name logic *out* of the query. You can easily (and much more cleanly) process that on the PHP side

Comment: @Dagon The query was made unnecessarily complex because there are two fields that were combined into a single one. Terrible idea if you ask me; but yes - they could easily be combined using a `BETWEEN` clause in that last `AND` clause. No offense to the OP, but it doesn't look like he knows what he's doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code above you open the `tr` tag in the first loop but never close it. Also in the first loop you print out the `Quarterly_yield` three times yet there is one column calculated for that result. Effectively you are printing out the same thing.

A couple of options - Print each result from each query in its own row:

```
// Loop through the results and print 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr id='centered' >\m";  
    echo "<td class='leftalign'>{$row['Quarter_Name']}</td>\n";
    echo "<td>{$row['Quarterly_yield']}</td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result8))
{
    echo "<tr id='centered' >\m";  
    echo "<td class='leftalign'>{$row['Quarter_Name']}</td>\n";
    echo "<td>{$row['Quarterly_yield']}</td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

Or you can create an array with the results you have and then print that array. This effectively will join the results together. So let's assume that the array is structured as such:

```
$results[Year-Quarter] = array(Year, Quarter, QuarterName, Result1, Result2)
```

then you can construct the array as follows:

```
$results = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $key = $row['Year'] . '-' . $row['Quarter'];
    $results[$key] = array(
        'Year'            => $row['Year'],
        'Quarter'         => $row['Quarter'],
        'Quarter_Name'    => $row['Quarter_Name'],
        'Quarter_yield_1' => $row['Quarter_yield'],
        'Quarter_yield_2' => 0,
    );
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result8))
{
    $key = $row['Year'] . '-' . $row['Quarter'];

    // Check if we have this key
    if (isset($results[$key]))
    {
        $results[$key]['Quarter_yield_2'] = $row['Quarter_yield'];
    }
    else
    {
        $results[$key] = array(
            'Year'            => $row['Year'],
            'Quarter'         => $row['Quarter'],
            'Quarter_Name'    => $row['Quarter_Name'],
            'Quarter_yield_1' => 0,
            'Quarter_yield_2' => $row['Quarter_yield'],
        );
}
```

and then print the results from the `$results` array

```
foreach ($results as $item)
{
    echo "<tr id='centered' >\m";  
    echo "<td class='leftalign'>{$item['Quarter_Name']}</td>\n";
    echo "<td>{$item['Quarter_yield_1']}</td>\n";
    echo "<td>{$item['Quarter_yield_2']}</td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```